# call reject with message on GT-S5300

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, call-screening, samsung-galaxy-pocket

my GT-S5300 has Gingerbread 2.3.6. Is there any way to upgrade or change this so that I can reject calls with a message / block calls in the same way that the bigger Galaxy (like the S III) can? Apps on Google Play and Samsung App Store are a bit clumsy. I can't seem to find something stock Android that can do this on the GT-S5300?